# Handling Overflow Row Data in a table

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have an HTML table in my web page and there may be many rows in it as it is generated dynamically. The problem i am facing is that When the row data overflows the available width, the whole table css is disturbed.

I need a solution such that if the row data overflows it should be split into multiple rows, as required to fit all the data.

The HTML is as follows:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td class='first' >From :</td>
<td class='second'>Gaurav Sachdeva &lt;gauravs23@ymail.com&gt;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class='first' >To :</td>
<td class='second' >nerdsachdeva@gmail.com
   &lt;nerdsachdeva@gmail.com&gt;nerdsachdeva@gmail.com
   &lt;nerdsachdeva@gmail.com&gt;nerdsachdeva@gmail.com
   &lt;nerdsachdeva@gmail.com&gt;nerdsachdeva@gmail.com
   &lt;nerdsachdeva@gmail.com&gt;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class='first'>Date :</td>
  <td class='second'>Sun, 1 Jul 2012 18:30:48 +0800 (SGT)</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

The css is as follows:

```
.first{
font-size:14px;
text-align:right;
font-weight:bold;
color: grey;
}
.second{
padding-left:10px;
font-size:14px;
font-weight: bold;
color:    black;
}
```

All css gurus out there....please help!

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean by *It should come in the next rows*? Do you want the table width to be fixed and split the text if it overflows? Or do you just want to align the text in the two columns?

Comment: yes i want the table width to be fixed and split the text into multiple rows if it oveflows.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem as I see it is really that “From :” and “To :” and “Date :” may each get split to two lines. To fix this, add

```
.first { white-space: nowrap; }
```

To fix another layout issue, which you did not ask about, consider adding this, too:

```
td { vertical-align: top; }
```

If the email recipient list in the data is really of the format in the example, it’s a bit odd and will be rendered oddly, as a line break may be inserted by a browser at any space but not after “>”. It is more normal to separate addresses by a comma or a semicolon and a space. If you cannot use spaces the, the practical choice is to insert `<wbr>` tags at allowable breakpoints, as in `John Doe <foo@example.com><wbr>Jane Doe <bar@example.com>`.

Comment: your answer is right on the target jukka.....thanks a lot....u made my job easy :)

Answer (score 1):

just replace this `css` with the below one
 Or Set Width For Your `Table` I Can See That There To `Width` defiened  For Your Table. `Width` May Fix The Problem

```
.first
{
font-size:14px;
text-align:right;
font-weight:bold;
color: grey;
}

.second
{
padding-left:10px;
font-size:14px;
font-weight: bold;
color:    black;
overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: @varun....overflow hidden will hide my data....this is not my requirement....i want to display all my data in the next rows if it overflows....

Answer (score 0):

ok check here now

```
<style>
.first{
font-size:14px;
text-align:right;
font-weight:bold;
color: grey;

}
.second{
padding-left:10px;
font-size:14px;
font-weight: bold;
color:    black;
    overflow:hidden;
}

</style>
<table cellspacing="5px" cellpadding="5px" style="width:525px;">
<tr>
<td class='first' style="width:57px;">From :</td>
<td class='second'>Gaurav Sachdeva &lt;gauravs23@ymail.com&gt;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class='first' style="width:57px;">To :</td>
<td class='second' >nerdsachdeva@gmail.com
   &lt;nerdsachdeva@gmail.com&gt;nerdsachdeva@gmail.com
   &lt;nerdsachdeva@gmail.com&gt;nerdsachdeva@gmail.com
   &lt;nerdsachdeva@gmail.com&gt;nerdsachdeva@gmail.com
   &lt;nerdsachdeva@gmail.com&gt;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class='first' style="width:57px;">Date :</td>
  <td class='second'>Sun, 1 Jul 2012 18:30:48 +0800 (SGT)</td>
</tr>
</table>
```